# PHP -modify value of last accessed element in multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am reading a [GEDCOM](http://genealogy.about.com/library/weekly/aa110100d.htm)-formatted family tree flat file, and producing an array from the data for staging into table. If I encounter the values `CONC <some value>`, then, instead of adding an element, I need to append `<some value>` to the value of the last element that was just inserted (regardless of dimension depth).

I tried with `current(...)` etc but does this work for a multidimensional associative array?

please consider following element in an array:

```
[@N163@] => Array ( [INDI] => Array ( [TEXT] => Some data of this person) )
```

if the next line reads "1 CONC including his profession"

instead of adding a line as such

```
[@N163@] => Array (  
                [INDI] => Array ( [TEXT] => Some data of this person)  
                [INDI] => Array ( [CONC] => including his profession) )
```

I would like the array to look as follows:

```
[@N163@] => Array ( 
                [INDI] => Array ( [TEXT] => Some data of this person including his profession) )
```

What I have researched thus far:

`end($theArray)` 
to set pointer to last inserted element followed by `$theArray[key($theArray)] = ....` to update this element.

But I did not get this method to work for multidimensional arrays and/or it became really messy.

And:

merging two arrays using e.g. `+=` notation,
but this only seems to overwrite a new element, not affect the last one, if keys are same

And:

examples with `foreach` calls, which does not help in my case.

Hope somebody can shed some light... many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you adding `$array[@N163@][INDI][TEXT] = 'smtng';` you can save position

```
$pos = &$array[@N163@][INDI][TEXT];
```

And if you need concatenate,  write

```
$pos .= "concate line";
```

Comment: wonderful! Of course, $pos is the actual thing, unlike &$pos... will try it now, Thanks for quick reply!

Comment: Sorry, i lost `&` :) Result of "quick" :)

Comment: i've changed answer - this is last inserted element. No value